# ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) Invalid Cloud Source Repository URL provided when using cloud function gen2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am trying out cloud functions gen2, but somehow the cloudbuild that builds the function cannot find the cloud source repository URL. This seems undocumented in the [official doc from google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy).

The same function deploys without an issue when I remove the **--gen2** tag in the deploy command, so I am sure it doesn't come from my code.

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - beta
  - functions
  - deploy
  - ${_SERVICE_NAME}
  - --project=${_PROJECT}
  - --region=${_REGION}
  - --source=${_REPOSITORY_PATH}
  - --trigger-bucket=${_TRIGGER_BUCKET_NAME}
  - --runtime=python39
  - --memory=128MB
  - --entry-point=${_ENTRY_POINT}
  - --service-account=${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}
  - --set-env-vars=OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME=${_OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME}
  - --gen2 # When I remove this, the function deploys without an issue.
options:
  logging: 'CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY'
```

Source path: _REPOSITORY_PATH

> https://source.developers.google.com/projects/muse-speech-devops/repos/github_bbreton-muse_muse_notion_speech_integration/moveable-aliases/dev/paths//functions/launch_transfer

**Cloudbuild error**

```sh
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) Invalid Cloud Source Repository URL provided. 

Must match the following format: 

https://source.developers.google.com/projects/<projectId>/repos/<repoName>. 

Specify the desired branch by appending /moveable-aliases/<branchName>, 

the desired tag with /fixed-aliases/<tagName>, 

or the desired commit with /revisions/<commit>.
```

Comment: You maybe touched a limit of the integration. When you look to the [documentation of gcloud function deploy --source](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source) the source repository is clearly mentioned. When you look to the [documentation of gcloud run deploy --source](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--source) it mentions a zip on GCS or local file, nothing ou Source Repository. (Cloud Functions v2 is based on Cloud Run behind the scene, that's why I searched on that). I reach  Cloud Functions team to ask more details on that.

Comment: Just before, can you share the _REPOSITORY_PATH value?

Comment: Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere, I added the _REPOSITORY_PATH, but as mentionned before, it works with the exact same configuration on the gen1 cloud functions.

Comment: Is the double slash // between paths and functions normal? In addition, is it a plain value? or is it dynamically generated? If dynamically, can you share the pattern that you use?

Comment: It is dynamically generated, the // is normal, it doesn't work on gen1 without it

Comment: Here my guess: in the error message you have that URL: ` https://source.developers.google.com/projects//repos/`, the projectID is missing, and your substituions variable might be wrong. But it doesn't explain why it works with gen1 and gen2....

Comment: The error message was pooly formatted by SO, it did not show the <projectId> but I checked, the Project ID is set correctly, this is so strange

Comment: Yep, I pinged the Cloud Functions team and sent them the link of that question. I expect to have an answer next week!

Comment: Feedback from Google Cloud Functions team: "support for Cloud Source Repositories will be available shortly after GA". No ETA for GA, so, you still have to wait a little. Stay tuned!